# In Archlinux, it has a valid IP address, but no connection could be established

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, realtek

Later I changed a wireless router, and everything became OK. Maybe there was something incompatible between the former router and the latter. Yet I can't get the reason.

--------update---------------------

```
~ % uname -a
Linux archlinux 3.17.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 7 23:43:32 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~ % ip route               
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.20  metric 303 
~ % cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.1.1

~ % lspci -vvv
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0726
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Region 2: Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
Kernel modules: rtl8723ae
```

Description: If it connects to the router, it **gets a valid IP address**, in my case, it's 192.168.1.20, but it has no connection with others.

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

returns nothing, and it won't get timeout error until I press Ctrl+C to cancel it.

What confuses me is that it runs **normally** connecting to other routers, and other devices runs **normally** connecting to the very router.
I just can't figure it out.

I've tried opensuse livecd and archlinux livecd, everything is OK. So I think there may be something wrong with the driver. So I compiled the wireless driver from [source](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), rebooted, and nothing changed.

Comment: Oh,you're using the `systemd` networking stuff? Had the same problem when I first did it - it didn't take name resolutions from the dhcp server. Look into `/etc/resolv.conf` - it's what did it for me. Though I see you're `ping`ing an actual ip and coming up empty and am less certain now...

Comment: What does `ip route` say?

Comment: Its probably the driver, whats your kernel version, updating kernel along with installing the new drivers fixed my realtek worries in the past

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for your help. I suspect the problem too, so I tried to control the wireless card via NetworkManager, yet nothing changed too. I've updated some outputs above.

Comment: @cjm Thanks for your help. I put the output in the question.

Comment: @ZirconCode Thanks for your help. You mean compile and update the kernel manually?

Comment: @UnixAgain yes, ive had luck since the 3.16 kernel. I see youre already on 3.17 so that might not be it then. The earlier kernels had a bug with some realtek drivers. Good luck!

Comment: Take a look at the Arch Wiki Wireless page, there's a complete section on [driver troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Troubleshooting_drivers_and_firmware), but you should probably read and follow the article from the start.

Comment: You have no iptables rules right? no blocked packets or anything in there?

Comment: @YoMismo No, there are no specific iptables rules. The only variable in this case is the wireless router, so I think the compatibility is the cause. The former one is from Gehua Network for free and the current one is my own Mercury one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a dns problem. Open /etc/resolv.conf and delete everything and type `nameserver 1.1.1.1` and save the file. If it fixes let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try with `arp -a`, see who is on your link. Add a static route to them, one of them will be the DHCP server, one the DNS. Then remove the routes.