# Arch i3wm valid ip, DHCP problem

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, dhcp

Related, but solved by workaround: [In Archlinux, it has a valid ip, but no connection could established](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175167/in-archlinux-it-has-a-valid-ip-but-no-connection-could-established)

My Arch system has gone "offline" some time ago.
I didn't bother to much because I used the Windows VM that had internet via network bridging. 
The funny thing is if I open NetworkManager and delete my connection, it immediately resets and internet is available under Arch until i3wm shows the IP in the status bar (~3s). 
Now I am trying to get it running normal again the third time and need some help.

```
uname -a 
Linux iamgroot 4.16.12-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 25:30:31 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
\# Generated by resolvconf #escaped for stackexchange codeformatting
domain fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

```
ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev en3ps0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.37 metric 202
default via 192.168.178.1 dev bridge_qemu_0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.37 metric 203
192.168.178.0/24 dev en3ps0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.37 metric 202
192.168.178.0/24 dev bridge_qemu_0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.37 metric 203
```

```
ping stackexchange.com
ping: stackexchange.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

```
ip addr
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc nonqueue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: en3ps0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bridge_qemu_0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:3d:7e:bd:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.278.37/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute en3ps0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: bridge_qemu_0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:3d:7e:bd:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.278.37/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute bridge_qemu_0
    inet6 fe80::2b75:33d9:ac58:3c55/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tap0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bridge_qemu_0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:0d:6e:2d:8f:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8a0b:fb95:5201:6d6a/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fc0d:6eff:fe2d:8faa/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would really appreciate all ideas.

Comment: One of the possibilities is deleting the resolvconf package.

Answer (score 0):

Either some peculiarity of your configuration is interfering with the `resolconf` package, or you were manipulating/copying over `/etc/resolv.conf` or some of your packages does not take into account having installed `resolv.conf`. Knowing arch linux, I do bet on the late probability.

The path of less resistance may be really better por an inexperienced user deleting the `resolvconf` package instead of trying to fix the `resolv.conf` symlink and/or finding out which package should be (re)configured.

`resolvconf` is also known to interfere also with VPNs, and I usually prefer to uninstall the package in my servers and desktops, even knowing my way how to deal with it.

Comment: I got it working now. It was not resolv.conf, as it seems. Instead killing dhcpcd did the job. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got lost. So you said before you deleted resolvconf. Have you?